# How can I make a cross-reference in items in an enumerated list in an appendix?

Tags: cross-referencing, appendix

Eg: the name of the reference should be A.1 instead of 1

```
\appendix
\section{App1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Something \label{app:1}
    
    \item 
\end{enumerate}

The reference is \ref{app:1}
```

And it shows "The reference is 1" instead of A.1.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and how you construct the enumerated list. Is there a single enumerated list in the appendix, or are there two or more such lists?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You might try redefining  `\theenumi`  with the `\AtAppendix` or `\ifappendix` command, from the `apptools\  package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the instructions

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumi}{\thesection.}
\makeatother
```

immediately after `\appendix`. Doing so instructs LaTeX to prefix the section number (or, as the case may be, letter) to cross-references to the level-1 enumerated items.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
A cross-reference to items \ref{app:list:2} and \ref{app:list:3}.

\appendix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumi}{\thesection.} % add a "prefix" in cross-references
\makeatother

\section{Supplemental material}

Here's an enumerated list:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Aaaa
\item Bbbb \label{app:list:2}
\item Cccc \label{app:list:3}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have another question. If I don't want the prefix temporarily in an enumerate list in a certain proof [e.g. a)bla b)bla ] , what should I do?